# Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)) in windows phone 8.1 app

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, unauthorizedaccessexcepti

I am trying to get Image from media capture element, When I try to open the file at that time this "Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))" Exception occured ...

```
try
        {
            var file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("takeImage.png", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

            if (file != null)
            {
                _mediaCapture.CapturePhotoToStorageFileAsync(ImageEncodingProperties.CreatePng(), file);
                ImageProperties imgProp = await file.Properties.GetImagePropertiesAsync();

                //LINE IS WHERE EXCEPTION HAPPENS..
                using (var imgStream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
                {
                    bitmap = new WriteableBitmap((int)imgProp.Width, (int)imgProp.Height);
                    bitmap.SetSource(imgStream);
                    PreviewImage.Source = bitmap;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { 
            ex.Message;
        }
```